# Looking for a book about a girl on a seemingly endless city bridge

Tags: story-identification, novel

I never had the chance to finish the book and I immediately forgot the name and couldn't find it again when I went back to the store.
In the book this girl lives on an island. Her father went away somewhere but left her a box. The box can't be opened ( i can't remember why).
So she travel to the bridge. It's basically a connections of ALL the world cities. Everything is on the bridge (or tiny islands)

Also everyone wears a mask and the girl has this friend that I believe is some kind of talking puppet? I can't remember clearly.
Anyways, the part I remember most clearly is in the city they pass a whore house. And there's a young girl in the house that has the ability to perfectly play any type of musical instrument. And so people come from all over trying to sleep with her (they can only sleep with her if she can't play the instrument).

The main protagonist sets about trying to free her form her servitude to the whore house master. (also the whore house has both men and women, it was super sexy lol).

She ends up barely succeeding in freeing her. And they escape to this "fountain" underneath the bridge that grants a wish, but at some exceedingly high cost. And things were climaxing and I think there was a cliffhanger. Someone may have been blinded.

Anyways, I've been searching for this book for at least 10 years. I really want to finish it.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: "Seemingly endless city bridge" made me think of 'The Bridge' by Iain M. Banks

Comment: That looks interesting!  But not quite it. This story was more in the realm of fantasy though.

Comment: @Richard My first thought as well. It's actually an Iain Banks, not Iain M Banks ;)

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but I am almost certain this is the *[Shadowbridge](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1896805.Shadowbridge)* series by Gregory Frost.

The main character is a female puppeteer who acts under a disguise of a male named Jax. Part of the disguise is a mask. Jax travels an endless web of city-bridges in search of her mother, a famous storyteller. Each bridge between arches had its own culture and language, but the arches acted as universal translators.

On one bridge, Jax encounters a member of a whore house, by the name of Diverus. This person is an indentured musician who can magically play any instrument. I recall the musician being a male, rather than a female, but with a similar deal in place.

Comment: Looks like a great answer, this might be it! :)